# What am I doing wrong with converting Fri, 15 Apr 2016 20:45:51 +0300 with strptime?

Tags: python, django, date, datetime

I have a feed date formatted as `Fri, 15 Apr 2016 20:45:51 +0300` and I am trying to convert it to something Django will accept.

Using the `datetime` module, I've attempted this:

```
date = datetime.strptime(e['published'], "%a, %d %m %Y %H:%M:%S +0000")
```

**Error**

```
ValueError: time data 'Fri, 15 Apr 2016 20:45:51 +0300' does not match format '%a, %d %m %Y %H:%M:%S +0000'
```

Comment: if the feed is parsed by `feedparser` module then [check `e.published_parsed`](http://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/date-parsing.html)

Answer (score 3):

Use the `%b` specifier for the abbreviated month and the `%z` specifier for the timezone, as per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('Fri, 15 Apr 2016 20:45:51 +0300', "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z")
datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 15, 20, 45, 51, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(0, 10800)))
```

Answer (score 1):

The time stamp you are trying to convert has a UTC offset of +3 whereas your pattern only accounts for UTC time.

This will take care of it regardless of the timezone

`date = datetime.strptime(e['published'], "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z")`